# Is my sha1 SSL cert safe if they expire before 2016?

Tags: tls, certificates, chrome

According to the Google [1], if my SSL cert expire after 2016 and at some points they will show a warning.

But, if all my cert expired before 2016, so I assume no action need to be taken to prevent the warning, right? (Of course except the renewal)

[1] http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html

Answer (score 1):

> But, if all my cert expired before 2016, so I assume no action need to be taken to prevent the warning, right?

Correct.

- Chrome (your link),
- Firefox (https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2014/09/23/phasing-out-certificates-with-sha-1-based-signature-algorithms/)
- and Windows (http://blogs.technet.com/b/pki/archive/2013/11/12/sha1-deprecation-policy.aspx)

should not complain.

Further reading if you're interested: http://blog.ivanristic.com/2014/09/sha1-deprecation-what-you-need-to-know.html